# JPA + JBOSS Hibernate NamedQuery not using column names

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Below is a snippet of my JPA Entity. When i run this in JBOSS with Hibernate DB2 dialect, the generated select query is using acctYymm instead of ACCT_YYMM causing -206 exception.

```
@Column(name = "ACCT_YYMM")
public String getAcctYymm() {
  return acctYymm;
}
```

SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=CARTUMLERE0_.**ACCTYYMM**, DRIVER=3.62.56

I tried to change the naming strategy to EJB3NamingStrategy and DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy, none of them seems to use the column names. I don't think this problem occurred before i implemented EmbeddedId and joined two tables. Could there be any co-relation ?

Adding my code:

Both Car and Pool Entity share PK embeddable class

```
@Embeddable
public class PK implements Serializable {
private String acctYymm;
private String carInit;
private String carNum;

@Column(name = "ACCT_YYMM", nullable = false, length = 4)
public String getAcctYymm() {
    return acctYymm;
}

//skipping getters and setters

@Column(name = "CAR_INIT", nullable = false, length = 4)
public String getCarInit() {
    return carInit;
}

@Column(name = "CAR_NUM", nullable = false, length = 6)
public String getCarNum() {
    return carNum;
}

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Car.findAll", query = "select umler from CarEntity umler join umler.poolEntity pool where umler.pk.acctYymm = :acctYymm and umler.pk.carInit = :carInit and umler.pk.carNum = :carNum")
@Table(name = "CART_UMLER", schema = "CARSCHEMA", catalog = "")
public class CarEntity implements Serializable{

@EmbeddedId
private PK pk = null;

public PK getPk() {
    return pk;
}

public void setPk(PK pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}


@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ACCT_YYMM", referencedColumnName="ACCT_YYMM"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CAR_INIT", referencedColumnName="CAR_INIT"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CAR_NUM", referencedColumnName="CAR_NUM")
})
private PoolEntity poolEntity;

private String carTyp;

@Basic
@Column(name = "CAR_TYP", nullable = false, length = 1)
public String getCarTyp() {
    return carTyp;
}

//skipping getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POOL", schema = "CARSCHEMA", catalog = "")
public class PoolEntity implements Serializable{

@EmbeddedId
private PK pk = null;

public PK getPk() {
    return pk;
}

public void setPk(PK pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

private String poolCd;

@Basic
@Column(name = "POOL_CD", nullable = false, length = 7)
public String getPoolCd() {
    return poolCd;
}

public void setPoolCd(String poolCd) {
    this.poolCd = poolCd;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully on your mappings, you'll see that you mixed property and field-based access.

You need to move the `@EmbeddedId` annotation from the field to the property:

```
private PK pk = null;

@EmbeddedId
public PK getPk() {
    return pk;
}
```

That goes for `PoolEntity poolEntity;` and `PoolEntity` `pk` attribute.

You need to be consistent about these mappings, otherwise, Hibernate is not going to find them.

Comment: Thank YOU so much @vlad-mihalcea. It worked so well. I should do some reading on the access types.

Comment: I bet it is worth a read. Just curious, does it have a paperback version ? Also, any plans to write an OpenJPA book? :)

Comment: The paperback version is [available on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Java-Persistence-Vlad-Mihalcea/dp/973022823X/). Why would I want to write about frameworks with a [2% market share](https://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Java-Persistence-Vlad-Mihalcea/dp/973022823X/)?